# Fitting 3D surface to lines

Tags: python, numpy, data-fitting

I'm trying to fit a 3D surface to about a dozen lines that I have, and am not sure how to do this. Here is what I have so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

healths = [80, 55, 17, 74, 57, 31, 22, 27, 87, 18, 43]
models = [np.poly1d([  4.28223697e+08,  -3.83982829e+09,   1.54420366e+10,
        -3.68735527e+10,   5.82979362e+10,  -6.43887895e+10,
         5.10598512e+10,  -2.94075941e+10,   1.22979001e+10,
        -3.69415039e+09,   7.80163678e+08,  -1.12121998e+08,
         1.05309654e+07,  -6.30329783e+05,   2.62939411e+04,
         2.78341012e+03]),
          np.poly1d([ -5.03569457e+08,   4.13162720e+09,  -1.53435594e+10,
         3.41117449e+10,  -5.05920921e+10,   5.27923363e+10,
        -3.98217265e+10,   2.19550281e+10,  -8.83588557e+09,
         2.56102119e+09,  -5.19347600e+08,   6.97912073e+07,
        -5.55518569e+06,   1.81867166e+05,   6.20639376e+03,
         2.98402109e+03]),
          np.poly1d([ -3.11228639e+08,   2.54546572e+09,  -9.38149455e+09,
         2.05935433e+10,  -2.99744015e+10,   3.04666739e+10,
        -2.21712463e+10,   1.16419022e+10,  -4.38122091e+09,
         1.15421540e+09,  -2.02321433e+08,   2.09660556e+07,
        -7.91107187e+05,  -7.20219187e+04,   1.09687645e+04,
         3.03857181e+03]),
          np.poly1d([  4.06376109e+08,  -3.40876838e+09,   1.29871912e+10,
        -2.97061518e+10,   4.54326091e+10,  -4.89753710e+10,
         3.82216169e+10,  -2.18390890e+10,   9.13394309e+09,
        -2.76751311e+09,   5.95043272e+08,  -8.79507913e+07,
         8.57795062e+06,  -5.35644516e+05,   2.33340505e+04,
         2.84100399e+03]),
          np.poly1d([  5.85452053e+08,  -4.32915850e+09,   1.44085701e+10,
        -2.85267351e+10,   3.74193127e+10,  -3.42989241e+10,
         2.26027183e+10,  -1.08749153e+10,   3.85568236e+09,
        -1.01690647e+09,   2.02670602e+08,  -3.11739277e+07,
         3.71627668e+06,  -3.28017937e+05,   2.02386281e+04,
         2.86613920e+03]),
          np.poly1d([  9.67869416e+07,  -7.20947000e+08,   2.42488924e+09,
        -4.85195211e+09,   6.39741251e+09,  -5.80880723e+09,
         3.67879424e+09,  -1.60522563e+09,   4.62972701e+08,
        -8.12821951e+07,   8.28251991e+06,  -1.33038835e+06,
         5.02616864e+05,  -1.06915704e+05,   1.18577216e+04,
         2.95626138e+03]),
          np.poly1d([ -8.21965398e+07,   6.66113115e+08,  -2.43997814e+09,
         5.35210028e+09,  -7.84838350e+09,   8.12834471e+09,
        -6.11475052e+09,   3.37560830e+09,  -1.35904117e+09,
         3.88270096e+08,  -7.36513971e+07,   7.69475814e+06,
        -4.68518014e+04,  -9.39497975e+04,   1.19806651e+04,
         2.94753388e+03]),
          np.poly1d([  4.44955719e+06,  -4.77598603e+07,   2.22221359e+08,
        -6.00377966e+08,   1.05765733e+09,  -1.28774804e+09,
         1.11742436e+09,  -7.01168814e+08,   3.19423895e+08,
        -1.05427538e+08,   2.51936455e+07,  -4.42976358e+06,
         6.05534885e+05,  -7.03349132e+04,   7.68758833e+03,
         3.07576987e+03]),
          np.poly1d([  1.86261524e+09,  -1.48587084e+10,   5.35778935e+10,
        -1.15449514e+11,   1.65600547e+11,  -1.66711318e+11,
         1.21000328e+11,  -6.40359773e+10,   2.47042057e+10,
        -6.87497940e+09,   1.35135140e+09,  -1.81534762e+08,
         1.59351750e+07,  -8.74063407e+05,   3.12551420e+04,
         2.78842491e+03]),
          np.poly1d([ -5.18981082e+08,   4.15882351e+09,  -1.50353149e+10,
         3.24186114e+10,  -4.64249139e+10,   4.65234117e+10,
        -3.34717498e+10,   1.74414418e+10,  -6.54853332e+09,
         1.73539847e+09,  -3.10545763e+08,   3.40774866e+07,
        -1.68331576e+06,  -5.34555987e+04,   1.21777897e+04,
         2.98675915e+03]),
          np.poly1d([ -2.06268790e+08,   1.62871951e+09,  -5.84473299e+09,
         1.26039508e+10,  -1.81881671e+10,   1.84965039e+10,
        -1.35835529e+10,   7.25000855e+09,  -2.78509188e+09,
         7.47231759e+08,  -1.30834535e+08,   1.24172387e+07,
        -7.93649306e+04,  -1.15924911e+05,   1.29540492e+04,
         2.97883998e+03])]

x = np.linspace(0,1,1000)
y = [[health]*1000 for health in healths]
z = [model(x) for model in models]

# Plot all the lines I want to fit a surface to
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
for yy, zz in zip(y, z):
    ax1.plot(x, yy, zz)

ax1.set_xlabel('SoC')
ax1.set_ylabel('SoH')
ax1.set_zlabel('OCV')

#Create many small surfaces (FOUND ON SO)
def fun(x, y):
  return models[healths.index(y)](x) # Select the model for the correct health, and evaluate at all x points

y = healths
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
zs = np.array([fun(x,y) for x,y in zip(np.ravel(X), np.ravel(Y))])
Z = zs.reshape(X.shape)
# end of what was found on SO

# Plot the surface
fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax2.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)

ax2.set_xlabel('SoC')
ax2.set_ylabel('SoH')
ax2.set_zlabel('OCV')

plt.show()
```

which gives the following plots:
[image: Lines to fit]
[image: Many surfaces plotted together]

But there are some problems with this.

1. This appears to just be a group of small surfaces being plotted, not 1 single surface that was fit to all the liens
2. I do not get an equation I can use to reproduce the surface(s) (unlike np.poly1d)

The reason I am trying to do this is because I want to be able to input just the `health` value (SoH on the plots) and then output a 2d line similar to the ones I am trying to fit.

In order to do this, I believe I need to fit a 3D surface to the lines. So, my question is, how can I fit a 3D surface to the lines and get the surfaces equation?

Thanks, let me know if anyone needs more details or if this has been answered. I was looking online for a while and could not find an answer that I could make work.

Comment: Your "lines" seem to represent data `SoC` vs. `OCV` and different lines seem to correspond to different `SoH` values. So you can just use a (cubic spline) interpolation for each `SoC` value along `SoH` for all points of all lines. The fact that the data points of all lines seem to be similar with respect to `SoC` makes that even easier. Otherwise you could interpolate that as well. So to recap: Lay out a 2D grid (in your example `Soc` dim. is already given by the data points and the lines' positions provide `SoH`). Then you can perform an interpolation along `SoH`.

Comment: @a_guest I'll try that out, thanks

Comment: To do an actual fit you first need a model, i.e. some function f(SoC, SoH) = OCV which contains some parameters. This function hast to be able to somehow "follow" the behavior of your lines for a specific set of parameters. Do you have an Idea how such a function could look like?

Comment: hey @obachtos I should have added that detail. The list "models" contains a few 15th order polynomials of the curve. SoH is to choose which of the models to use. So I do already have f(SoC, SoH) which outputs OCV

Comment: Well, not quite. Your polynomials are only valid for specific lines, a null set to be precise. In other word, you can only choose specific values SoH. However, if I understand correctly you are exactly interested in the space between. So you either have to come up with a model function for that or you use the interpolation suggested by a_guest.

Comment: yes, that's right. getting that model is exactly what im trying to do. I had thought fitting a surface to those lines would be a good way.

Comment: But how do you want to do a fit if you don't have a model function?

Comment: To enter the discussion: a 15th order polynomial seems a complete overkill. I assume that those polynomials are generated from 16 data points. It would be, hence, much better to generate the surface from those points. Especially as some randomness sort of renders the coefficients uncorrelated already providing the hint that this is not a good way to go. Bsplines might work, but not sure if they are implemented for surfaces. Anyway, providing the original data might help to crate sort of a meta model.

Comment: With the original data points you should try [scipy.interpolate.griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html)

Comment: ...or you try [NURBS](http://nurbs-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)